# git commands in python , not able recognize a valid git

Tags: python, git, python-2.7

I am doing a simple git command test , which is working fine from a bash terminal.

```
$ pwd 
#/mnt/some_dir
$ git clone git@github.com:my-git/my-repo.git 
$ cd my-repo
$ git status
```

now I am running same from a python script (part of same repo my-repo.git) , below are the content (after git clone from bash)

```
import os

print os.getcwd()
os.chdir('my-repo')
print os.getcwd()

os.system('git status')
```

getting below log with git failure $ python /mnt/some_dir/my-repo/python.py

```
 /mnt/some_dir
 /mnt/some_dir/my-repo
 fatal: Not a git repository: /mnt/some_dir
```

My question is why the git status is not executing inside git repo even after I am doing a change dir in previous step?

I even tried with subprocess , but getting same error

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'status'], cwd='/mnt/some_dir/my-repo')
fatal: Not a git repository: /mnt/some_dir
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, it works for me.

Comment: Is `/mnt/some_dir/my-repo` actually a symlink to it's parent?

Comment: I would expect `fatal: Not a git repository: /mnt/some_dir/my-repo` as the error so perhaps your `os.chdir()` did not work as you expected and your code ultimately executed in the parent directory I think.

Comment: Have you tried the code with some other random directory you created yourself? Instead of the git-repository. If that should work, then you know at least that the problem is related to git.
BTW: Are you forced to use Python 2.7? I would highly recommend you Python 3.

Comment: @L3viathan The same code works fine on my local machine , but somehow throwing the error while running on remote machine.

Comment: And why not to use GitPython module? https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: With remote machine you mean if you are logged in via ssh on a remote machine?